# How can my chrome extension check whether a user has signed in to the rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, google-chrome-extension, session-cookies

I have a rails 3 app that creates a sessions with:

```
cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
```

How can my chrome extension check whether the user has signed in and then retrieve the current user id so that the extension is being used with the appropriate account?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`chrome.cookies.*`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/cookies.html) API, it allows reading cookies from specified domains.

Comment: If I am testing the extension with localhost and then QA and then prod, I would have to check all domain cookies to see if the user is logged in. Would you say some other way may be better? like localstorage?